# Webpack build fails with code that does not exist

Tags: webpack

My webpack build is failing with some line of code. So I delete the line of code. Same issue, same code. The code does not exist anywhere else, it is a unique throw error message. Is there some kind of .. cache or memory to reset? To do a clean build so to speak?

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (144:158)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
|       default:
>         throw new Error(`Blablabla ${foo[a] ?? a}.`);
|     }
|   }
```

Comment: For some reason now, it no longer likes ??.

Comment: Check your Node.JS version

Answer (score -1):

There are many reasons that can lead to this error.

1. I see that you are using the wrong quote (probably a copy from another source, like a Word document). Use the right quote: "'" instead of : "`".
2. When you deleted the line, did you save your file? It is another possibility.
3. To clean the cache, use: `npm cache clean -f`.
4. If it is a problem with the `node_modules` folder, you can delete them and rebuild them again by using the command: `npm prune`.

I hope that it will help.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the formatting ^^

Comment: Those aren't "the wrong quote", it's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Also this is an issue with webpack (and a subsidiary one with babel), not npm.